# Sidecar shows blank screen. Unless I reboot

Tags: macos, sidecar

My iPad shows this blank screen after it disconnects due to poor connection and I start sidecar back up. After rebooting the computer, and connecting with Sidecar, the problem is resolved.

I don't want to keep rebooting, however, every time this happens. So far, everything I've read refers to toggling 'Mirror Displays' as a potential solution. This doesn't work for me.
[image: this blank screen]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `display preferences` > `arrangement` > `tick` and then remove the tick from `mirror display` option. For more info see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250711652)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be a problem of the [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209455) feature. Deactivate Handoff both on your Mac and your iPad. Wait for a couple of minutes and then turn Handoff on again on both devices and take care that both devices are unlocked at the same time!